# Laravel relationships use Where

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

This relationship is in my `Maintenance.php`

```
  public function contactedContractor()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ContactedContractor::class, 'maintenance_id');
    }
```

I want to use the relationship in a query in my controller

```
$contractor_maintenances = Maintenance::whereHas('contactedContractor', function ($query) {
                                                    return $query->where('contacted_contractors.user_id', '=', 8);
                                                })
                                                        ->where('contacted_contractors.user_id', $contractor_user_id)
                                                        ->latest('maintenances.created_at')
                                                        ->get();
```

but the where clause is not working giving me this error

`Unknown column 'contacted_contractors.user_id' in 'where clause`

How do I use the where clause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've passed in the query. `Maintenance` doest not have `user_id`

```
->where('contacted_contractors.user_id', $contractor_user_id)
```

Pass your query as below.

```
$contractor_maintenances = Maintenance::whereHas('contactedContractor', function ($query) use ($contractor_user_id) {
                                return $query->where('user_id', $contractor_user_id);
                            })->latest('maintenances.created_at')->get();
```